# JavaScript for(-each) loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON-Array and want to loop though it. I know that there is no foreach-loop (like in PHP), but is there a possibility to access the field index of the array?

This is my json:

```
{
    'username': 'Karl',
    'email': 'xyz@abc.xx',
    'user_id': 5,
    ...
}
```

I have some span elements on my page with a data-field attribute. E.g:

```
<span data-field="username">xyz</span>
```

The json-array is the return of an ajax-request. With it, I want to replace every element where the `data-field=""` matches the array-index.

Right know, I do it this way for each element in the json-array:

```
$("[data-field='username']").text(data.username);
$("[data-field='email']").text(data.email);
```

But with more and more elements this becomes a little bit ugly^^

Any other possibilties? I read something about transforming the json to an object, but I have no idea how to do.

Comment: what ever you have posted is already a object.

Comment: Check out `Object.keys` or `for` .. `in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for each loop in javascript would look like below.

```
for(var key in Json){
   $("[data-field='"+ key +"']").text(Json[key]);
 }
```